# What is the numberformat code for Short date?

Tags: vba, excel

I know that I can write the following to format a number as a date with the appearance yyyy-mm-dd:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

I know that I can also write:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

and all kinds of things.

But is there a way I can set the number format to become a general short date and leave it up to the user's system to decide the exact appearance?

I'm looking for an expression like:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "Short Date" '(<-This does not work)
```

Comment: If you just set it to General and assign a date to it, it should automatically use Short Date format for the system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bit tricky. If you have a look at a cell's properties, format tab, category Date, you will see some formats beginning with an asterisk (*), those respond to the changes of the user locale. Try setting your cell to the first element, short date, then get its numberformat value in the immediate window with `?activecell.NumberFormat`. You'll see that it is `"m/d/yyyy"`, so your snippet does the job well. Just try changing your locale setting in control panel, the format of the cell will change accordingly.

Comment: I agree.  On my system setting NumberFormat "m/d/yyyy" makes the cell display in system Short Date (in my case thats "dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: I don't quote understand why this workds, but it does. "m/d/yyyy" get's automatically converted into my default locale which is YYYY-MM-DD. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Please try this

```
 Format(Range("A1"), "Short Date")
```

It will return the system short date value.